# After installing new Rails version, tests failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

After installing Rails 4.0.2 from 4.0.0, my tests are failing. It works in the browser (development). This also happens with Rails 4.0.3.

```
20) Error:
UserFlowsTest#test_login_and_browse_site:
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
app/views/posts/_post.haml:10:in `_app_views_posts__post_haml__439576154_44475312'
app/views/posts/index.haml:1:in `_app_views_posts_index_haml__194952016_42560292'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:21:in `index'
test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UserFlowsTest>'
```

Here is line user_flows_test:14

```
post_via_redirect "/users/login", username: users(:chloe).username, password: 'passpasspass'
```

Here is line _post.haml:10

```
%a{href: user_path(post.user)}= post.user.username if post.user
```

The documentation is little help: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-post_via_redirect

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#helpers-available-for-integration-tests

---

Test output:

```
-----------------------------------------
UserFlowsTest: test_login_and_browse_site
-----------------------------------------
Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 21:35:13 -0500
Processing by UsersController#login as HTML
  Rendered users/_login.haml (0.0ms)
  Rendered users/_new.haml (41.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.haml (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_right_bar.haml (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 47.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 21:35:13 -0500
Processing by UsersController#loginCreate as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"chloe", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
"*********************************************************************** 1"
Redirected to https://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 160ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 21:35:13 -0500
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendered posts/_vote.haml (7.0ms)
  Rendered posts/_post.haml (18.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms
E-------------------------------
```

This is the end of UsersController#loginCreate

```
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  p "*********************************************************************** #{session[:user_id]}" 
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in! Last seen from #{lastIP}."
```

This is from the Rails console

```
irb(main):009:0> p = Post.first
irb(main):011:0> app.user_path(p.user)
=> "/users/1"
```

---

Here is the simplest error

```
 21) Error:
PostsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    app/views/posts/_post.haml:10:in `_app_views_posts__post_haml__1028637779_43998912'
    app/views/posts/index.haml:1:in `_app_views_posts_index_haml__48584214_43731948'
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:21:in `index'
    test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
```

So simple...

```
  test "should get index" do
    get :index                       ###### LINE 26
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)
  end
```

---

More info

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails console
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading test environment (Rails 4.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> Post.pluck(:user_id)
=> [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Can you post the salient action of your "/users/login/" controller? Could it be a strong parameters issue? The easiest way to diagnose would be to binding.pry at the point just before the redirection.

Comment: It's not related to login, since it is redirecting. It seems to fail when displaying post, which is after the login. This is what it does: `session[:user_id] = @user.id;
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in! Last seen from #{lastIP}."`. And it's not just that one, dozens of tests are failing similarly.

Comment: sorry - I edited my original comment.

Comment: can you determine what the session[:user_id] is? It seems from your error like it is nil.

Comment: Ok it equals 1. I added more output.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Given what you've shown, the only thing I can think of is that the `post.user` is nil at the time the link is rendered. If you're passing a collection of user.posts into the _posts partial, I don't know why that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change  a user id from 0 to 1 in the post fixtures. That set of a chain reactions of changes. I also put the `if` on a different line in the HAML instead of at the end of the line, just in case. The HAML properties seem to be evaluated before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your user has not id:

```
post.user.id => id
```

This would mean post user is not persisted?

Comment: All tests passed before changing the version. The user has an id in the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is testing a collection route, :index, but the test is showing an error on a member route, as indicated by it looking for an :id.

You're either instantiating your partial (app/views/posts/_post.haml) that has a link_to in it with a nil id or your routes file is the problem.

Comment: No it wasn't the route file. `user_path(post.user)` is a member route. It was because in version 4.0.0, Rails would allow a fixture with a relationship id that did not exist, but in version 4.0.3, it throws an exception if the relationship id doesn't exist. Post.user_id was set to 0 in the fixtures, and user id 0 didn't exist in the fixtures. The user ids started with 1. So it died.